# How to apply a tween animation to multiple objects. (optimization)

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization, dotween

I'm using DoTween to animate floating text in Unity.
All floating text has simple, one same animation.
Codes goes like

```
public void FloatText(Vector3 pos, int value)
    {
        var obj = textObjQueue.Dequeue();
        obj.SetActive(true);
        obj.transform.position = pos;
        obj.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = value.ToString();
        TweenText(obj);
    }

    void TweenText(GameObject obj)
    {
        obj.transform.DOMoveY(pos+Vector3.up, .2f).OnComplete(() => PoolObj(obj));
    }
```

All floating texts should be played in different place and time, but has same animation- moving upside from their original position.
Literally there are tons of floating text played(50 per second I guess), and I want to know if there are any technique to reduce its cost.
Any helps would be great. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You should first look at the profiler to see how much the cost even is, and if it slows down  it is for which part

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.